# How to send JSON requests to a remote server?

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to send a JSON rpc to a remote web-server. The client-side of my application must be completely javascript. The choice of the client library should be independant from the json-rpc implementation on the server-side. I don't need json-over-http. Simple json objects over tcp/ip is enough for my use-case.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean completely javascript? Javascript in a web browser or stand-alone javascript like Node.js?

Comment: Where is your client-side code running? If a browser, then you're going to get HTTP whether you want it or not. Do you already have a communication mechanism in mind? If not, will normal AJAX be sufficient? If you answer these questions, someone can point you at a better solution.

Comment: My client runs inside a web-page. What I need is a lightweight implementation of JSON-RPC. It seems JSOLait is the tool to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try jsolait. AFAIR it has support for JsonRPC 1.0 over sockets.

Comment: I'll look at the specs, but when you say 'over sockets' you mean that no web-server is required ? So it's JsonRPC over tcp, and not over http?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are connecting to a remote web server, you will have to use HTTP.

You can use XMLHttpRequest for this from Javascript or you can use a library such as jquery that packages it up in an easier to use API. Many Javascript libraries support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Ajax with jQuery. Dead simple.

[JQuery Post Documention](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)